# Pressing back button and current activity status

Tags: android

If I have activity A starting activity B. Then when on B I press the back back button and I go back to A. Now if I go to B again, will Oncreate be called?

Thanks

Comment: you should start to basic

Comment: Yes. Everytime you start an activity it will call onCreate. You need to have look at Activity Life cycle for better understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes every time you enter into the activity onCreate method is called.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does. I have an app that displays a toast from the onCreate method in B, and it displays the toast every time you open it.